# Why the set of theorems of another set must be a theory.

Tags: logic

A is a set of first order sentences. B is the set of the theorems derived from A. Is B necessarily a theory?

Comment: If a theory is a set of sentences that is closed under derivations ...

Comment: How to draw a contradiction from having a theorem of B which does not belong to B?

Comment: It may be a little more clear to say that $B$ is the set of statements 'that can be derived' or 'derivable' from $A$

Comment: Isn't every set of sentences is a theory? If not, you should mention in the question the definition of "theory" that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One overkill way is to use the completeness theorem. Suppose $M$ is a model of $A$, and $B$ proves $\varphi$. Can you show that $M\models\varphi$? (This part uses soundness.)

This implies that every model of $A$ satisfies $\varphi$ - using the completeness theorem, what does that tell you about $\varphi$ and $B$?

---

EDIT: As Andres says, this level of overkill is a really bad way to solve the problem, which is purely combinatorial in nature; I just thought this was amusing.

Comment: A million thanks!

Comment: Noah, what's the point of bringing models into the argument? Plus, invoking completeness increases the requirements of the metatheory. The simple combinatorial idea gets buried beneath technicalities.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, and I did say that this was overkill - I just thought it was amusing. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: Noah, can you show me the combinatorial method?

Comment: @ZZL It depends on the specific proof system you're working with. If you have the "cut" rule, it's trivial; if you don't, then it may take some work. But the idea will always be the same: given a proof of p from B, isolate the finite subset B_0 of B used in the proof, and let q be the conjunction of all the sentences in B_0; now show that q is in B (by &-introduction in some form) and "paste" the proofs of q from A and of p from q together to get a proof of p from A.

Comment: @Noah I've got it, thanks.